# Android Check Application Status

Tags: android, status

I have a question about Android application status. I want to know that am I able to check whether application is alive or dead, visible or on background. I need to make a decision according to application status in my broadcast receiver.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you could supply details about the "decision", perhaps we can help you.

Comment: Simply, if application alive I want to step over the start up process, then jump the target activity. All I want to know how to check application status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when your receive broadcast your application is guaranteed to run. That's because broadcast can not be received without application process started first. And if there were no components active (like activities) when broadcast is sent, then application process is started for the sole purpose of processing this broadcast.

As for the other part, detecting if any Activity is currently active and/or visible - I haven't seen any API calls for this. There are might be some workaround (like manually keeping the counter in a singleton), but as far as I know there is no direct support for this. Though I might be wrong.

Comment: Without knowing the status of specific activity, I can not decide whether to show notification or not. For example, if the `ChatActivity` is running, notifications are not allowed, if it's not running, then I have to show notification to remind user. These work should be done in `BroadcastReceiver`. Is there any good approach for this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You determine if your "application" is "alive" by seeing if the data you loaded in your "start up process" exists. If it does, use it. If it does not, run the "start up process".

Comment: ok this is a solution but I wonder that whether Android has an API level support for this. Thanks.

Comment: @baris3437: You don't need "API level support for this". It is ordinary Java, checking to see if a static data member holding whatever you cached from your "start up process" is `null` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Within Android, it is standard practise to track 'changes' to the various states. You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Within the specific lifecycle related methods, you can perform specific actions as deemed appropriate.

Comment: it is not a good answer, I don't need to track the activity lifecycle, I need to check the Application status: Alive or dead, visible or invisible. or Application has at least one activity alive ?